# Determining $A \triangle B = B - C \implies A \subseteq B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Stumbled upon this question in today's exam. Had trouble doing it, so I'd like to verify if my reasoning was valid:

> Determine the truth value of
>
> $A \triangle B = B - C \implies A \subseteq B$

I believe that it is true, as I couldn't find a counterexample with diagrams. I tried to prove this directly, but it didn't seem to be leading me anywhere.

As a last resort, I decided to prove it by contradiction. I'm not entirely sure if what I did was even reasonable:

**Suppose** that $A \not \subseteq B$. Therefore, a possible diagram is this:
[image: VENN DIAGRAM]

Where:

$A = \{1,2\}$

$B = \{2,3\}$

$C = \{4\}$

Clearly $A \not \subseteq B$, as our supposition says.

However, this happens to contradict our premise.

The premise says that $A \triangle B$ should be equal to $B - C$. Let's calculate them:

$A \triangle B = B -C$

$\{1,2\} \triangle \{2,3\} = \{2,3\} - \{4\}$

$\{1,3\} = \{2,3\}$

Which is false, because $\{1,3\} \not = \{2,3\}$.

Since our supposition $A \not \subseteq B$ leads to a contradiction, it can't be. Thus we prove that $A \subseteq B$.

So, $A \triangle B = B - C \implies A \subseteq B$ is true.

---

Was that valid? As a side note, would it have been possible to prove directly?

Comment: It is a little strange. Is there any constraint of $C$?

Comment: @Falang: I can't find any other reference to $C$ other than $B - C$ in the question. Now that you mention it, yeah, it is pretty odd.

Comment: Also, your example is not persuasive. I guess you should show the case for an arbitrary $C$ instead of a designed one.

Comment: @Falang: No constraint on $C$ is required. Since $B\setminus C$ is just an arbitrary subset of $B$, the result is equivalent to the following statement, which does not mention $C$: if $A\mathbin{\triangle}B\subseteq B$, then $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: You are right. I prefer your claim " $A\Delta B\subset B$, then $A\subset B$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That argument does not prove the result: it merely shows that one instance of the contrapositive of the result is true. An actual proof might go like this:

> Suppose that $A\nsubseteq B$, and let $a\in A\setminus B$. Then $a\notin B$, so $a\notin B\setminus C$. On the other hand, $a\in A\setminus B\subseteq A\mathbin{\triangle}B$, so $$a\in(A\mathbin{\triangle}B)\setminus(B\setminus C)\;,$$ and therefore $A\mathbin{\triangle}B\ne B\setminus C$.

This shows that if $A\nsubseteq B$, then $A\mathbin{\triangle}B\ne B\setminus C$, which is logically equivalent to the desired result.

This can also be phrased as a proof by contradiction, but it’s not necessary to do so if you know that *p implies q* is logically equivalent to *not-q implies not-p*, its contrapositive.

**Added:** Note that the result can be restated in a way that may make it a little more transparent. Since $C$ is completely arbitrary, $B\setminus C$ can be any subset of $B$. Thus, the stated result is equivalent to this one:

> if $A\mathbin{\triangle}B\subseteq B$, then $A\subseteq B$.

Since $A\mathbin{\triangle}B\subseteq B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$, the hypothesis that $A\mathbin{\triangle}B\subseteq B$ implies that $A\setminus B\subseteq B$. Since $A\setminus B$ contains no elements of $B$, this is possible only if $A\setminus B=\varnothing$, which is equivalent to saying that $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: Aw, there goes that question in my test :(

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a comment on your reasoning, but an alternative approach.*

Let's calculate for which sets the left hand side holds:
\begin{align}
& A \triangle B = B - C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"set extensionality; expand definitions of $\;\triangle\;$ and $\;-\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \;\not\equiv\; x \in B \;\equiv\; x \in B \land x \not\in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: replace one equivalent of $\;x \in B \Rightarrow x \not\in C\;$ by another"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \;\not\equiv\; x \not\in B \lor x \not\in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: $\;\not\equiv\;$ to $\;\equiv\;$; DeMorgan"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \;\equiv\; x \in B \land x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"introduce $\;\cap\;$ using its definition; set extensionality"} \\
& A = B \cap C \\
\end{align}
The answer you're looking for follows directly from this.